# Refactor $(this) out of multiple click functions

Tags: jquery, refactoring, this

I have the following simplified code:

```
       $(".button1").click(function() {
          var container = $(this).closest('.someClass');
          container.doStuff();
          specificFunction1();
        });

           $(".button2").click(function() {
          var container = $(this).closest('.someClass');
          container.doStuff();
          specificFunction2();
          specificFunction3();
        });
```

Can I refactor out `$(this).closest('.someClass');` and make it a global variable so that `$(this)` always refers to the correct button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a somewhat unexpected solution, that nevertheless reduces repetitive code so it works for me:

```
    $(".button1").click(function() {
          var container = getContainer($this);
          container.doStuff();
          specificFunction1();
        });

           $(".button2").click(function() {
          var container = getContainer($this);
          container.doStuff();
          specificFunction2();
          specificFunction3();
        });

   function getContainer(container){
    return container.closest('.someClass');
    }
```

Comment: Opinions on this?

Comment: I don't see how this reduces repeat code. in your original question you had 5-6 buttons and each event handler had this code:
    var container = $(this).closest('.someClass');
now each handler has this code:
    var container = getContainer($this);

your solution doesn't reduce the number of lines needed to implement this feature and this code would fail code reviews because your adding another level of indirection. this is similar to assigning this to that. you need to learn how context works in JavaScript

Comment: Your solution also creates a function with a `return` and requires the line `$container.call(this)` in each `.click()`. So as fas as "number of lines needed", I don't see much difference

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
$(".button1, .button2").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.someClass').doStuff();
});
```

You need `$(this)` because it references the actual button which was clicked and allows you to chain more jQuery functions on the button itself.

If you want to avoid multiple use of `$(this)` within the anonymous function then you can do:

```
$(".button1, .button2").on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest('.someClass').doStuff();

    if($this.hasClass('button1')){
        specificFunction1();
    }
    else if($this.hasClass('button2')){
        specificFunction2();
    }
});
```

Comment: There are more buttons with different code/functionality, cant combine like that. will edit the question now

Comment: @AndreyDoronin There are lots of ways you can structure your code but you will not get away from needing to call `$(this)` because you are chaining additional jQuery methods. `var $this = $(this);` is a common caching method and is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't scale well with 5-6 buttons and similar number of unique functions that each button has. This would produce just a lot of `if else` statements and one huge click function :(. Sorry for not specifying this in the question

Comment: In which case I think your comment "but you will not get away from needing to call $(this)" is the right answer

Comment: @AndreyDoronin Yep, I had a funny feeling you would have more than 2 buttons but your question only shows 2 buttons so I took my chances.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `call`, `apply` and `bind` to pass the context:

full example included:

```
$('body').append('<button class=button1>tester</button><div class=someClass />')

var $container = function() {
  return $(this).closest('.someClass');
}

$("#tester-btn").click(function() {
  $container.call(this);
});
```

Comment: Wouldnt this produce `Cannot read property 'closest' of undefined`?

Comment: the `this` keyword will never be undefined, it will always be a reference to the function, where it was invoked, or the window object

Comment: You keep changing your answer, putting and then cutting out entire chunks of code. At the time of this comment 1) you mention `apply` and `bind` that are nowhere to be seen +  2) `class=button1` vs. `#tester-btn`